# Python - Parsing Json format input

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need to make a data parsing that come from another program in JSON format:

```
import json

input = '''
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
        )
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person Object
                (
                    [arr:Person:private] => Array
                        (
                            [cf] => DRGMRO75P03G273O
                            [first_name] => Mario
                            [last_name] => Dragoni
                            [email] => mario.dragoni@yahoo.com
                            [phone] => 558723
                            [uid] => dragom
                            [source] => USRDATA
                        ) 
                )
            )
        )
'''
```

I tried:

```
data = json.loads(input)
```

But I get:

```
**ValueError:** No JSON object could be decoded
```

Perhaps the fault is due to lack of field separators?

Edit:

The input was generated by a *php* **print_r**, I replaced it with **json_encode**

Comment: that isn't JSON format

Comment: your provided string isnt json!!

Comment: that `input` string appears to have been generated by PHP's `print_r` function, see examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1):

your function is correct.

but the provided json string is wrong

in fact the input is a mixed array and class object

you can import json in python like this:

```
import json
j = json.loads('{"one" : "1", "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}')
print j['two']
```

Comment: I realized later that the input was wrong. Thank you all!